# Find the word and replace with html tag using regex

Tags: html, regex, replace, tags, tex

I have a text equation like: `10x^2-8y^2-7k^4=0`.
How can I find the `^` and replace it with `<sup>2</sup>` in the whole string using regex.  The result should be like:

[image]

I tried `str = str.replace(/\^\s/g, "<sup>$1</sup> ")` but I’m not getting the expected result.

Any ideas that can help to solve my problem?

Comment: Try `.replace(/\^(\d+)/g, '<sup>$1</sup> ')`. Do you need to also manage whitespace around these values in a specific way?

Comment: No its enough..i got it my answer thanks for your help.

Comment: If i can applied with dual tag function in same  single regexp like this:- `"^" replace with <sup>$1</sup>` and `"⌄" replace with <sub>1$<sub>`.What should i do? please tell how can i  modified the code?

Comment: You already accepted an answer. Ask the person who answered, or ask a new question. If it does not exist, of course, or it will be a dupe.

Comment: Is the work done in javascript, or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like

```
\^(\d+)
```

It matches the `^`, captures the exponent and replace with

```
<sup>$1</sup>
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xX3vQ4/1).

**Edit:**

To meet your new *demands*, check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/La1zed2o/1/). It handles the `sub` as well using replace with a function.

Comment: Thanks a lot .clear and simple code.And also fulfilled my expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Your current pattern matches a caret followed by a space character (space, tab, new-line, etc.), but you want to match a caret followed by a single character or multiple characters wrapped in accolades, as your string is in TeX.

```
/\^(?:([\w\d])|\{([\w\d]{2,})\})/g
```

Now, using `str = str.replace(/\^(?:([\w\d])|\{([\w\d]{2,})\})/g, "<sup>$1</sup>");` should do the job.

---

You can make a more generic function from this expression that can wrap characters prefixed by a specific character with a specific tag.

```
function wrapPrefixed(string, prefix, tagName) {
    return string.replace(new RegExp("\\" + prefix + "(?:([\\w\\d])|\\{([\\w\\d]{2,})\\})"), "<" + tagname + ">$1</" + tagname + ">");
}
```

For instance, calling `wrapPrefixed("1_2 + 4_{3+2}", "_", "sub");` results in `1<sub>2</sub> + 4<sub>3+2</sub>`.

Comment: Thanks Michael. If i can applied with dual tag function in same  single regexp like this:- `"^" replace with <sup>$1</sup>` and `"⌄" replace with <sub>1$<sub>`.What should i do? please tell how can i  modified the code?

Comment: Hmm... Whats with the curly braces part? How is that necessary?

Comment: @prasanthsadhana Please see my updated answer, I've added a function that you can use for any string, prefix and tagname.

Comment: @ClasG Judging by the TeX tag on the question OP is trying to parse a TeX string. TeX groups characters using accolades. For example: 2<sup>5+2</sup> is written as `2^{5+2}`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.